# Should I register my Kindle DX?

Tags: kindle

A few days back I purchased a second hand Kindle DX online. But realized that I could not change the settings, I had to register it first.

So, should I register it? I fear that if I do, I'll get locked out of the device (as it is not mine originally and I don't know the details)

Comment: This might be a better question for Amazon support directly, though someone here may know.